# Adjust Array Value in Shopping Cart based on User login state

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

How would I adjust individual values within the `$_SESSION array` depending on whether the user is logged_in or not logged_in. So basically the array values equate to the individual item prices within the shopping cart and will be adjusted if the user logs in or logs out of the `SESSION`.

Here's my current code:

**PHP**

```
 if(!empty($_SESSION)){

    foreach($_SESSION['basket'] as $b){

    if ($session->logged_in) { $b['itemprice'] = ""; }

            $sub_total = $b['itemprice'] * $b['itemqty'];
            $total = $total + $sub_total;

          // display contents of shopping cart

         } 
            } 
    elseif (empty($_SESSION)) { ?>

    // display message informing the user that their cart is empty
```

**MYSQL**

```
              $itemids = array();
              foreach ($_SESSION['basket'] as $item) {
              $itemids[] = "'" . $item['itemid'] . "'";
              }

              $itemids_str = implode(',', $itemids);

              $query = mysql_query("SELECT product_id, price, price_100 FROM product    WHERE product_id IN ($itemids_str)");
              while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)) { }
```

The closest I've come to getting this to work is each product in the cart is given the same price which changes if the user logs in or out. However, I need each item to change to the new price specific to that items product ID.

Some of our members receive a discount on certain items, so once the user logs in from being a `GUEST` to the registered `USER` the price needs to be changed on page refresh.

An example being :

```
**Logged in == FALSE**

Item 1      Price: 100.00 
Item 2      Price: 100.00

**User logs in (Logged in == TRUE)**

Item 1      Price:  85.00
Item 2      Price:  94.00
```

I hope I've been clear - any advice would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPTION A:

```
function updateCartPrices()
{
    $itemids = array();
    foreach ($_SESSION['basket'] as $item) {
        $itemids[] = "'" . $item['itemid'] . "'";
    }

    $itemids_str = implode(',', $itemids);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT product_id, price, price_100 FROM product WHERE product_id IN ($itemids_str)");
    while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        foreach ($_SESSION['basket'] as $key => $item) 
        {
            if($result['product_id'] == $item['itemid'])
            {
                $_SESSION['basket'][$key]['itemprice'] = ($_SESSION['logged_in']) ? $result['price'] : $result['price_100'];
            }
        }
    }
}


if(!empty($_SESSION)){

    updateCartPrices();

    foreach($_SESSION['basket'] as $b){

            $sub_total = $b['itemprice'] * $b['itemqty'];
            $total = $total + $sub_total;

          // display contents of shopping cart

         } 
            } 
    elseif (empty($_SESSION)) { ?>

    // display message informing the user that their cart is empty
```

OPTION B (performance better):

```
function getLoggedInPrices()
{
    $itemids = array();
    foreach ($_SESSION['basket'] as $item) {
        $itemids[] = "'" . $item['itemid'] . "'";
    }

    $itemids_str    = implode(',', $itemids);
    $query          = mysql_query("SELECT product_id, price, price_100 FROM product WHERE product_id IN ($itemids_str)");
    $prices         = array();

    while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $prices[$result['product_id']] = $result['price'];
    }

    return $prices;
}


if(!empty($_SESSION)){

    $loggedInPrices = getLoggedInPrices();

    foreach($_SESSION['basket'] as $b){

            if($_SESSION['logged_in'])
            {
                $b['itemprice'] = $loggedInPrices[$b['itemid']]; 
            }

            $sub_total = $b['itemprice'] * $b['itemqty'];
            $total = $total + $sub_total;

          // display contents of shopping cart

         } 
            } 
    elseif (empty($_SESSION)) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - This is sort of what I need, however, the Members price isn't based on a formula as such. It's taken from SQL database so 'if ($session->logged_in) $price would equal 'price_100' column from the database where product_id matches the ID from the item in the basket.

Comment: I'm sorry, i updated my answer. Do you mean something like this?

Comment: Thanks again - I've tried both OPTIONS. Option A displays the logged_in price for both GUEST Users and Logged in Users. Option B doesn't change the price of the items whatsoever. Any idea why?

Comment: Is the `$_SESSION['logged_in']` variable `true` while logged in?

Comment: `getLoggedInPrices()` need to return an Array of the logged in prices. You can check if it's filled by putting `print_r($loggedInPrices)` after `$loggedInPrices = getLoggedInPrices();` after that if `$_SESSION['logged_in']` is `true` you add `echo 'Loggedin price filled for product'.$b['itemid']` after `$b['itemprice'] = $loggedInPrices[$b['itemid']];` so you can check if the it changes the prices.

Comment: Thanks for all your help - made a slight alteration to your answer to reflect my working function.